# JQuery post not working in document but is working in console?

Tags: ajax, post, jquery

I have a page which needs to use $.post() but for some reason the exact code works when I run it from the firebug console but not from my script? My script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dl_btn').click(function () {
        $.post(
            "news_csv.php",
            $("#dl_form").serialize(), function (data) {

            alert('error');

            if (data == 'success') {
                alert('Thanks for signing up to our newsletter');
                window.open("<?php echo $_GET['link']; ?>");
                parent.Shadowbox.close();
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It isn't the link as that does get printed properly but it gives me an error on line 140 of jquery min, I have tried using different versions of jquery and to no avail. I really dont understand why this isn't working.

When I changed from $.post to $.ajax and used the error callback I did receive an error of 'error' and the error is undefined?

Don't suppose anyone has any ideas? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your click button placed inside a form element?

Cause doing so, clicking on it will not only trigger the onClick event you have binded to, but form submit as well, so you will end up in a case where your browser is executing both requests in parallel - with unpredicted outcome, of course.

I tried the same code with an element that does not trigger form submit and it worked as expected.

One point though: if you plan to use simple string as a return value and to do something with it (display it or so) then is ok to do what you do right now.  However, if you have more complex response from the ajax request, you should specify the response type (xml, json..) as the last parameter of the post method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aha once I took the button out of the form it worked fine, the ajax call was being aborted because the page was being reloaded, I didn't even notice! Thank you soo much!

Comment: But it was only a button element inside a form so why was it triggering the form to submit as I thought only the onclick event would be triggered?

Comment: You need to return false in your click. This will override the behavior of the `<input type='submit' />` event which probably submits the form. If you must have JS enabled for your form then `action=""` is the safest, but if JS can be disabled then leave `action` alone